# Doubt in area of an infinitesimally thin ring

Tags: calculus

I want to find out area of a ring of an infinitesimal width in a derivation of electrostatics. So here's how my teacher explained it. Let the inner radius of thin ring be $r$ and outer be $r + dr$.
Area of thin ring
$$dA = π(r + dr)² - πr²
        = π(r² + (dr)² + 2r dr) - πr²
        = π(dr)² +π(2r dr)
        = π(2r dr).$$
My doubt is that why do we ignore the term with $(dr)²$. What determines to ignore a term or contain the term in the expression like $π(2r dr)$ is contained? If we say that $(dr)²$ is infinitesimally small then can't we say that the term with $dr$ is also infinitesimally small to be ignored.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what happens as you make $\text dr$ smaller and smaller? What happens to $(\text dr)^2$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70376/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92925/123208

Comment: dr^2 approaches zero much faster than dr, as dr approaches zero.  It might be illustrative if you look in your calculus book for the Taylor series of a function, and think about what happens to the higher order terms as dr gets infinitesimally small.

Comment: user12076043, are you in high school or college?

Comment: Would this be better on Mathematics SE?

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $dr$ is infinitesimal small which tends to zero i.e. $dr\to 0$ but $dr\ne0$. Now the square of infinitesimal small length i.e. $(dr)^2$ is even much much smaller.

We can say that $2\pi rdr$ is much larger than $(dr)^2$. Thus adding $(dr)^2$ to $2\pi rdr$ doesn't make any valuable difference. Therefore $(dr)^2$ is neglected while adding to $2\pi rdr$ although $2\pi rdr$ is very small.
$$2\pi rdr+(dr)^2\approx 2\pi rdr\quad \quad (\because \  \ \ (dr)^2\ll2\pi r dr)$$
Take a simple example of very small number say $10^{-15}$ if we add it to its square $(10^{-15})^2$ it makes no difference we can say that sum is approximately $10^{-15}$ i.e. $10^{-15}+(10^{-15})^2\approx10^{-15}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a dx which is small but finite.  If dx = 1E-6 m, then (dx)^2 = 1E-12 m.  Then add them.

Comment: You are correct that we can ignore 1E-12m but you have considered dx finite here. I have learned that when we write ∆x as dx then x tends to be zero. If we can use dx then can't we contain (dx)² in our expression as it also tends to zero only.

Comment: @user12076043 , Even though $dx$ tends to 0 , it is required for integrating the body . That means $dx$ has a physical significance. It is the smallest part(in this case, area) that you can measure in a body and it is assumed that the body cannot be divided anymore. But $dx^2$ has no physical significance because it is same like $(thickness)^2$ which means nothing

Comment: What do you mean by (thickness)^2 doesn't have a meaning?

Answer (score 0):

We have π()²+π(2) = π(dr + 2). We need to keep dr somewhere, but as dr -> 0 it becomes more and more negligible compared to 2r so (dr + 2) can be replaced by 2r.

More generally, consider quantities x and x². If x = 1, x² = 1, if x = .5, x² = .25, if x = .25, x² = .06 etc.

As x gets smaller, the ratio of x² to x gets smaller (as it equals x). So in the limit x -> 0, we can ignore x² terms compared to x.